# Apache: Rewrite then Proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, mod-proxy

So, I have two servers, let's call them nice#server and a#another#server

nice#server is what clients will talk to and is running Apache2 performing basic reverse proxy for simple services, a#another#server hosts a proprietary application server on port . I need to completely rewrite two url's before they get passed through, but just add a folder to all other URLs.

Some Examples below:

```
User Requests: nice#server/
Apache requests a#another#server:8080/appname

User Requests: nice#server/css#css
Apache requests a#another#server:8080/appname/css#css

User Requests: nice#server/a
Apache requests a#another#server:8080/appname/command1?name=option1

User Requests: nice#server/b
Apache requests a#another#server:8080/appname/app2?name=option2
```

I have done a lot of Googling and test on this but cannot seem to get it to work, sorry I've not kept the links that i've tried!!! I have stripped the vHost file right back down for now.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName              service#domain#com
  ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/service-domain-com-error.log
  LogLevel                warn
  CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/service-domain-com-access.log combined
  ProxyPreserveHost       On
  ProxyRequests           off
  ProxyPass               / a#another#server:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse        / a#another#server:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this fixed with a bit of trial and error. posting solution here in case anyone else is having the issue.

## Working configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName              service.domain.com

    ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/internal-fqdn-error.log
    LogLevel                warn
    CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/internal-fqdn-access.log combined

    RewriteEngine           On
    RewriteRule             ^/a$ /appname/command1?name=option1 [PT]

    ProxyPreserveHost       On
    ProxyRequests           off
    ProxyPass               /       http://a.another.server:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       http://a.another.server:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```